# What is distributed caching system good for?

Tags: distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

What is meant by distributed caching framework? I am looking for an answer which would provide an example scenario and then go on to explain how a distributed caching framework like Oracle Coherence would benefit in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, caching is putting oft-used data into memory in order to improve performance.

So what then is "distributed caching" vs "local caching" and what kinds of distributed caching is there?

So the simplest form of caching is local caching. What local caching means is that a single machine (typically a server) brings data into memory locally usually by making a database call and then storing that data in RAM. This is a suitable approach for a problem where a single server can handle all of your scalability needs now and into the forseeable future.

However, what happens if you need to add more and more servers in order to meet demand?

As soon as you add more servers, you have to start thinking about which data will be stored in RAM on which servers. One simple case is called "fully replicated" in which every single server contains the same data in memory. This works fine for cases where often used data is quite small, and server memory is quite large. In this case there are several solutions that may be a fit for you, as this is not a particularly difficult problem.

The harder problem is, what if the data set that is often used is much larger than the RAM size of a single server? In this case, the RAM Cache must be distributed across multiple servers. The typical implementation of this is a distributed hashmap, aka a distributed key-value store.

If you want to understand a bit more, you can download a ebook chapter [here that explains about the deployment architecture of distributed cache](http://hazelcast.com/resources/getting-started-with-hazelcast/), in this case using Hazelcast, an open source data grid that is often used as an alternative to Oracle Coherence.

To provide an example, think of a web application like an ecommerce store. In order to provide the best performance to ecommerce customers, the web site owner needs to be able to have enough server capacity to handle lots of traffic, even on high shopping days like holidays and "Black Friday" like days.

The most often used content on ecommerce sites are images and descriptions, pricing and reviews of the product catalog.

So in this case, you could imagine that such content could be quite large, for some ecommerce stores the total amount of content can be terabytes in size.

Now one approach is just to buy one single humungous server. But why would you not want to do that? The simple answer is flexibility and price/performance. What if you need 100 servers to handle the huge load on Black Friday? Or what if you are launching an incredibly popular product that goes viral? You may need a large number of servers... but the next day or maybe a week later, you may need many fewer machines.

So why would you pay for a single huge box that is perfect for one day in the year, and leave it mostly unused for the rest of the 364 days?

Also, buying a single huge box is typically more expensive than buying lots of commodity boxes for exactly that reason-- the smaller boxes are a commodity. That is why FaceBook and Google all use thousands of commodity boxes to run their services instead of one giant computer.

So to hit the optimal points of flexibility to scale up or scale down, to pay the best price for hardware that you can actually use, and to achieve the highest In-Memory performance for data processing or transaction processing or caching, you should consider using an In-Memory Data Grid product like Oracle Coherence. Or there are also several good alternatives to Oracle Coherence in open source that you can find using Google.

Answer (score 0):

What is meant by distributed caching ?
*In order to distribute the load of cache queries among different nodes, data is partitioned among many (Note: many but not all) cluster nodes in the cache server.*

**Benefit:**

[image]

**Fault-Tolerant**- As the above picture states in the absence of node 2 / JVM 2 data can be served from the other node.

**Read and write:** Linear performance scalability for reads and writes.

https://blogs.oracle.com/felcey/coherence-clustering-principles
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/caching-what-why-and-how-with-hazelcast/